# Number of Points on the edges (number of districts at country border)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, borders

I'm extremely new on QGIS and I have a district map of India which looks like this.
[image: India]

I want the data of districts situated on the border. Basically, with each district there will be another column stating a binary output(0/1, situated at the border/not situated at the border) which is apparently the number of points on the edges. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume as the result you expect to have only those districts which are on the national border of India.
I'm not sure whether it's the best way but this could be done by using select feature inside QGIS. This can be used to select objects by marking them.

I put an HowToArticle in my answer:
[How to Use Select Features By Area in QGIS](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-use-select-features-by-area-in-qgis/)